# ImportError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work

Tags: keras, graphviz, importerror, pydot

I have seen similar issue but it is not solved either, so I decided to ask.

I am trying to visualize my model in keras using

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

First, it showed error

```
ImportError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.
```

Accordingly, I installed  pydot and graphviz through Anaconda prompt activating my environment using

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/t/TOKEN/j14r pydot
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/t/TOKEN/j14r graphviz
```

Then, I closed spyder and reopened it. When I run code snippet, it is still showing the same error. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209738/1959808

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keras plot\_model tells me to install pydot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188756/keras-plot-model-tells-me-to-install-pydot)

Comment: @loannis Filippidis, thanks, yes, it says _The path(s) to the installed GraphViz executables (dot, neato, etc.) need to be in the PATH environment variable, in order for pydot to find them. pydot used to search for those executables in earlier versions, but not any more._ If you mean this, I don't know how to do this, sorry for that, Can you be more specific on what to do step by step?

Comment: The answer mentioned above links to relevant information for path configuration.

Comment: yes I saw, but I couldn't get it work. What I am saying is I don't know how to put the paths to installed GraphViz exucutables (dot, neasto, etc) in the Path environment. I am a new user of windows actually

Comment: @loannisFilippidis, I found dot and neato executables in my _C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tfcnn\Library\bin\graphviz_ and added this to **system properties>environment varaibles>system variables>edit**. It is not working though!

Comment: I am not a Windows user. Perhaps rebooting is needed for the new path to take effect. On Linux systems usually the path is configured via `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 59):

The following commands solved the problem for me

1. ***pip install pydot***
2. ***pip install pydotplus***
3. ***sudo apt-get install graphviz***

Comment: And in Windows, because I had already installed conda, I used `conda install graphviz` instead of `sudo apt-get install graphviz` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Also, as mentioned below - restart the kernel.

Comment: Yes, using `sudo apt-get install graphviz` for graphviz instead of `pip install graphviz`

Answer (score 36):

It seems like you are using Windows. In that case, see [this SO Q&A stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092771/how-to-install-graphviz-2-38-on-windows-10)
and/or [this Keras issue on gitub](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/25).

Following hints from both sources, it seemed likely there was an install error and/or a path error. I used `pip uninstall` on all related packages, then:

```
pip install pydot
pip install pydotplus
pip install graphviz
```

Then:

- Download and install graphviz binaries from [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html)
- Add path to graphviz bin folder in system PATH

I was running a python script `myscript.py` within a Windows `cmd` window. I had to close and reopen that to refresh the PATH, but then `plot_model()` produced output fine.

Comment: Try looking if GraphViz is installed from conda. If so, remove it and install it from pip. This is what helped me solving this.

Comment: `I had to close and reopen that to refresh the PATH, but then plot_model() produced output fine.` This is the _pro_ tip.

Comment: If you are working in Pycharm, make sure to use the system interpreter of python, not the virtual interpreter that Pycharm automatically binds to every python project. File > Settings> Project aaa > Python interpreter , then choose the local bin directory, e.g. C:\Python310\python.exe

Comment: This worked for me. Restarting the command prompt was something I was missing.

Answer (score 20):

Solution found from: https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/69#issuecomment-483273641

I followed the advice of uninstalling and reinstalling pydot + pydotplus and that successfully solved the issue on my Windows 10 machine using Anaconda 3.

```
conda uninstall pydot
conda uninstall pydotplus
conda uninstall graphviz
```

then

```
conda install pydot
conda install pydotplus
```

Note: installing pydot also installed graphviz

Answer (score 19):

I solved this problem by installing :

```
conda install graphviz
conda install pydot
conda install pydotplus
```

PS: i called plot_model with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```

and it's working now.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me

Comment: This works for me too :-)

Comment: it worked for me as well. I first installed these packages with pip but that did not work. conda install worked

Comment: you are a hero!

Answer (score 10):

Restarting the Kernel solved the problem for me, without needing pydot-ng.

Answer (score 6):

Use next command to install them:

```
sudo apt install python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python-pydot-ng

Answer (score 6):

Using TensorFlow 2.3.0 on Windows 10 *without* Anaconda, the following (finally) worked for me:

1. Install [Graphviz 32 bit](https://www2.graphviz.org/Packages/stable/windows/10/msbuild/Release/Win32/) (64 bit didn't work)
2. Add Graphviz path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\bin` to system's and user's `PATH` environment variables
3. Install pydot-ng which is the [preferred pydot library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/vis_utils.py#L29-L41) used by TensorFlow 2.3.0

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

# model = Model(...)

plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

These commands work for me.  I did:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/t/TOKEN/j14r pydot
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/t/TOKEN/j14r graphviz
sudo apt install python-pydot python-pydot-ng graphviz
```

Comment: Just `conda install -c conda-forge pydot  graphviz` works

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
import keras.utils.vis_utils
from importlib import reload
reload(keras.utils.vis_utils)


from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model    
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

on win10 anaconda3
start your command prompt with run as administrator
then

```
conda install graphviz
```

This gives you *graphviz2.38* which works.
This beats the way downloading installers from  https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/#windows, which didn't work on my machine.
Then you can pip install pydot to make sure you have it.
Then restart kernel and it should be fine.
If not,
pip install graphviz, for it seems to be a necessary python wrapper.
I also tried `pip intsall pydot-ng  pydotplus` before the `conda install` command above. They didn't help at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it to late. But i think it will help to someone.I use ubuntu 22.04. In my case first i installed:

```
sudo apt install graphviz
pip install pydot
pip install pydotplus
pip install graphviz
```

The second step is restart the computer.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered this issue, and none of the suggested solutions worked for me because I am using a Mac. So, if you're a Mac user like me, use the commands below:

```bash
pip install pydot
pip install pydotplus
pip install graphviz

brew install graphviz
```

You need to install `graphviz` with brew to be able to use the `plot_model`

Answer (score 1):

For me, all I had to do was install graphviz and pydot:

On Python3:

```
pip3 install pydot-ng
pip3 install graphviz
```

On Python2:

```
pip3 install pydot-ng
pip3 install graphviz
```

That resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import keras
import pydot
import pydotplus
from pydotplus import graphviz
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
keras.utils.vis_utils.pydot = pydot
```

This worked for me. Check this out -> https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/69

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Install in my virtual environment (Python 3):

```
pip3 install pydot_ng
```

Install at machine level (it didn't work if installed only in environment):

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

To import it:

```
import pydot_ng as pydot
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pydot and pydotplus using pip. Download exe for graphviz and install. Add graphviz to PATH. Restart and check. It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Graphviz from https://www.graphviz.org/download/
2. Import:

   from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot

   from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

Answer (score 0):

> pip install pydot pip install jupyterlab

go to https://graphviz.org/download/ and install graphviz

import os
#os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin/'

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model = titanic_preprocessing , rankdir="LR", dpi=72, show_shapes=True)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook.  I tried everything in this thread and others and nothing worked.  And then I found this and it worked for me:

1. close jupyter notebook.
2. open new Anaconda prompt.
3. conda install --channel conda-forge pygraphviz

Open Jupyter notebook and make sure you have the following imports:

- from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
- import pydot
- import pydotplus
- from pydotplus import graphviz

Answer (score -1):

Even after installing `pydot`, `pydotplus` and `graphviz` I was met with an error that `dot cannot be found in environment PATH`

so I installed graphviz-2.38.msi from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/

But, the problem still persisted until I switched from `**keras.utils.plot_model**` to `**tf.keras.utils.plot_model**`

[See image, Plot model now works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfd6w.jpg)

Comment: This indicates that you have imported both keras and tensorflow as tf imported.  The current recommendation is to NOT import keras and instead use tf.keras whenever you need access to keras functions.

Answer (score -1):

For jupyter notebook after installing the requirements restart the notebook. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

It works in Spuder IDE. The main idea is to reduce the number of imported libraries.

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import pydot
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This answer shows how to use the plot_model function, which is something that OP has demonstrated they know how to do. The question is about resolving a pydot and graphviz installation error.

Answer (score -1):

Take care when installing the Pycharm module, do not forget to note that you are in the conda environment.

[packages layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETMHS.png)