# pydot error even though it's already installed

Tags: python

I have already installed 'pydot' but there are still errors like this

File "C:\Users\Eko AB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 20, in _check_pydot
    'Failed to import `pydot`. '

ImportError: Failed to import `pydot`. Please install `pydot`. For example with `pip install pydot`.

Comment: does this helps? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605558/importerror-failed-to-import-pydot-you-must-install-pydot-and-graphviz-for-py