# How to connect input layer to an extra layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I was wondering if it is possible to create a customized network structure where the input layer has an extra connection to a hidden layer that is not adjacent to the input layer by using `tensorflow`. As an example, suppose I have a simple network structure as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 

m = 200
n = 5
my_input=  np.random.random([m,n])
my_output =  np.random.random([m,1])

          

my_model = tf.keras.Sequential([  
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(my_input.shape[1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) 
])   
                    

my_model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))
res = my_model.fit(my_input,  my_output, epochs=50, batch_size=1,verbose=0)
```

Is there a way that the first layer having the input values can have an extra connection to the third layer that has the ReLU activation? While doing so, I'd like to have different constraints in each connection. For example, for the connection coming from the previous layer, I'd like to use `GlorotNormal` as my weight initialization. As for the extra connection coming from the input layer, I'd like to use `HeUniform` initialization.

I tried to visualize what I have in mind below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Keras` functional API and `tf.concat`:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 

m = 200
n = 5
my_input=  np.random.random([m,n])
my_output =  np.random.random([m,1])

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((my_input.shape[1],))  
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='softmax')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal())(x)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(my_input.shape[1], kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform())(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(tf.concat([x, y], axis=1))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

my_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

dot_img_file = 'model_1.png'
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(my_model, to_file=dot_img_file, show_shapes=True)
my_model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))
res = my_model.fit(my_input,  my_output, epochs=50, batch_size=1,verbose=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try. May I ask where you found this info? I went through the website and could not find any information.

Comment: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

Comment: Thanks for the image. Looking at it now, how am I going to constraint weights in those two connections differently. My intention is to use different weight structures for ````x```` and ````inputs````?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was wondering how you created the diagram representing the network. It looks really neat. I'm referring to ````model1_1.png````.

Comment: Check the code in the answer before I call model.fit()

Comment: Oh okay! I thought you were reading a png file and calling it thru tensorflow.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I have a quick question. If I want to add another connection from Input to tanh, should I define a new ````y_extra = tf.keras.layers.Dense(my_input.shape[1], kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeUniform())(inputs)```` or can I go ahead and use ````y```` that is already defined. Sadly, I'm not able to use plot_model since tf gives me error.

Comment: Yeah you can define a new layer. You probably need to install the Graphviz library to plot your model.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes, I did but it still gives me an error. I followed every step shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605558/importerror-failed-to-import-pydot-you-must-install-pydot-and-graphviz-for-py