# Graphviz reports not finding executables although they are in my system's Path

Tags: windows, python-3.x, path, graphviz

I have downloaded the graphviz files and put them in the directory C:\graphviz of my PC (I am running Windows 10).

[image]

Then I added the address of the executables to the System's PATH :

[image]

Still when I run the diagnostic code:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table')

dot  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS

dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')

dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')

print(dot.source)  # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE

dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)  # doctest: +SKIP
```

I get an exception:

```
// The Round Table
digraph {
    A [label="King Arthur"]
    B [label="Sir Bedevere the Wise"]
    L [label="Sir Lancelot the Brave"]
    A -> B
    A -> L
    B -> L [constraint=false]
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py in render(engine, format, filepath, quiet)
    128         try:
--> 129             subprocess.check_call(args, stderr=stderr, **POPEN_KWARGS)
    130         except OSError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    285     """
--> 286     retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    287     if retcode:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in call(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    266     """
--> 267     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    268         try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    706                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 707                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    708         except:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    991                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
--> 992                                          startupinfo)
    993             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ExecutableNotFound                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1b23fb1e1f3e> in <module>()
     14 print(dot.source)  # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
     15 
---> 16 dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)  # doctest: +SKIP

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in render(self, filename, directory, view, cleanup)
    174         filepath = self.save(filename, directory)
    175 
--> 176         rendered = backend.render(self._engine, self._format, filepath)
    177 
    178         if cleanup:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py in render(engine, format, filepath, quiet)
    130         except OSError as e:
    131             if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
--> 132                 raise ExecutableNotFound(args)
    133             else:  # pragma: no cover
    134                 raise

ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'test-output/round-table.gv'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

The following might also help in the diagnosis:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the directory `C:\graphviz\bin` is 9n your system path (i.e. the variable Path in the picture you presented). Try to run in a terminal window: `where dot.exe` and `dot --help` and see what happens.

Comment: @albert Thank you.  I did as you suggested.  Please see my post with the result of these actions.  I am not sure what these messages imply and I don't know what to do to correct the problem.

Comment: Strange, a bit a contradiction on the one hand it finds the dot (dot -V) on the other hand it doesn't (where dot.exe). Can you try `where dot`?

Comment: You created a new environment variable called `graphviz`, and assigned a value to it. You didn't append the respective directory to your `PATH` variable. You also seemingly tried to escape your path separators. This is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\graphviz\bin` should be appended to system variable `path`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699078/8037585